# Retrieve which replica instance was used for mongo query using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use the [official node.js mongodb client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) for performing Mongo queries targeting a cluster via a connection string similar to:
`mongodb://euwest1-01,euwest1-02,uswest2-01/dbname?replicaSet=mycluster&readPreference=nearest`. As you see, I include in my cluster some differently geo-located instances and "nearest" should guarantee the right replica to be picked.

Nevertheless, I would like to know which one was used to perform any query, so that I can include to each of my operations' log the mongo replica that was used to perform the query.

Hacking around the [Cursor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html) object, I can get what I want in an hacky way:

```
const find = (query, callback) => {

    let cursor = coll.find(query);
    cursor.toArray((err, items) => {
      console.log(cursor.server.ismaster.me);
      callback(err, items);
    });
};
```

But I feel like this can break in any moment as not documented + it seems limited to the Cursor interactions (so I wouldn't know how to achieve the same for a `findOne` method).

Is anyone aware about a clean way to do this?

Comment: Doing this from the application side seems the wrong way to me. I'd suggest to periodically monitor the connected clients to each replica set member and alert in case you find a client which _should_ not belong to the client list. However, the way "nearest" works, makes it absolutely possible that a client from the other end of the world connects, since nearest basically means "the one with the _current_ lowest latency". I can not remember the interval in which the latency is determined, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in using the APM interface.

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/management/apm/

This lets you access the context of each operation being run by the driver and is really meant for APM providers but if you want to keep track or log how your ops are executing it might be useful for you.

```js
var listener = require('mongodb').instrument({
  operationIdGenerator: {
    operationId: 1,

    next: function() {
      return this.operationId++;
    }
  },

  timestampGenerator: {
    current: function() {
      return new Date().getTime();
    },

    duration: function(start, end) {
      return end - start;
    }
  }  
}, function(err, instrumentations) {
  // Instrument the driver  
});

listener.on('started', function(event) {
  // command start event (see https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/command-monitoring/command-monitoring.rst)
});

listener.on('succeeded', function(event) {
  // command success event (see https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/command-monitoring/command-monitoring.rst)
});

listener.on('failed', function(event) {
  // command failure event (see https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/command-monitoring/command-monitoring.rst)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that it is not the best solution, but you can use the .eval() function to create a function which return server_info & result, like this:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').eval(function construct(){
    var res = db.getCollection('mycollection').find(query);
    var explain = res.explain()['server'];
    return {'server':explain,'result':res.toArray()};
})()
```

which return something like :

```
{
   "server" : "myservernode.mydomain:27017",
   "result" : [ 
       // your query results
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I investigated the explain functionality, unfortunately 1) It is available only for cursor - so the findOne problem persists - 2) When I run it for a cursor in node, the server I get from there seem different than what I have when I inspect `cursor.server.ismaster.me` so now I'm confused :(

Comment: 1) So findOne problem is normal because findOne() method returns a document rather than a cursor. You may use instead find() method with a filter to get only 1 element

Comment: 2) Use eval() more than your method. The eval() command evaluates JavaScript functions on the database server, and explain() func. show more informations (including the real execution cluster ip (server) adress) about the execution of the query.   If you need an equivalent to findOne(), you still may use some filter with find() function to get only one document in the result.